# WooCommerce does not loading the whole .mo file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to load the woocommerce language files from the child theme with this code (functions.php in child theme):

```
function weg_localisation() {
    unload_textdomain('woothemes');
    load_textdomain('woothemes', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/woocommerce/woocommerce-en_US.mo');
    unload_textdomain('woocommerce');
    load_textdomain('woocommerce', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/woocommerce/woocommerce-en_US.mo');
}
add_action('init', 'weg_localisation');
```

... but this way I am loading only 50% of the strings (50% translated).

When I paste the .mo file in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages it`s working fine - translated at all.

How to fully load the translations for woocommerce from the child theme? I need this at this time.